Can a possessive adjective (tuum) be used as a predicate accusative?
Like the English: "Make it yours", can we do "Fac/redde/puta id tuum"?
I find no reason to rule that usage out, but, so far, I find no classical examples either.
Do we have any example of this usage?

English "yours" isn't just the possessive adjective used substantively, there's a derivational step involved.

https://booksnbackpacks.com/latin-possessive-pronouns-and-adjectives/

Related

It seems to be possible. Here is a nice example from Seneca (quoting Lucilius):

Non est tuum, fortuna quod fecit tuum. (SenPhil.Ep.8.10.2)


What Fortune has made yours is not (really) yours.

